# Loading Overlay On Top Of showModalBottomSheet

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I have created a `LoadingOverlay` Widget that sit at the very top of the widget three (after `Scaffold` widget) that takes Widget as child, put it inside `Stack` Widget and put custom `Spinner` Widget below it. As expected it sit on the top of screen, blocking input when loading state activated.

But at the same page i have a function that call `showModalBottomSheet` to render `BottomSheet` Widget. The problem is my custom loading overlay will render below the `BottomSheet` Widget.

How can i put my custom loading overlay on top of all Widget including `BottomSheet` ?

Instead of

```
BottomSheet
LoadingOverlay
Screen
```

to

```
LoadingOverlay
BottomSheet
Screen
```

LoadingOverlay Widget snippet

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Stack(
    children: [
      ScreenWidget(),
      CustomLoadingOverlay()
    ]
  )
}
```

Screen Widget snippet

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: LoadingOverlay(child: _buildScreen()); // show bottom modal function inside _buildScreen()
  )
}
```

Any help is appreciated as i am new to Flutter. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

to overlay on anything you can call your `CustomLoadingOverlay()` with `showDialog` function.

But keep in mind `showDialog` is a function and should be called it's not a render object as far as I remember, try calling it with state changes or initState.

you can close it by `Navigator.pop(context)`

here is an example:

```
showDialog(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => CustomLoadingOverlay())
```

Comment: CMIIW, showDialog append to route and can lead to unwanted side effect, that is why i am trying to avoid it.

Comment: what kind of side effects are we talking about